# Does anybody know if other distros are capable of overwriting existing OS's?

Tags: system-installation, distro-recommendation

I'm looking at some other distros to play around with on my older computers and was wondering if I need to format the drives for certain distros before I do a USB install. I was looking at Lubuntu, Linux Mint, Zorin, Deepin, and a few others. I know with Ubuntu you are able to overwrite existing OS's but I'm not clear on the others.I have a Desktop PC I'm putting it on.

```
HP Pavilion a1517x
200 GB HD
2 GB RAM
```

Comment: I would recommend that you download the 32bit version of any other the distros that you do try because of the low specs of your computer.

Comment: Yes, I've already downloaded the Zorin 32bit ISO. I wanted to see how similar it is to Windows 7 because I have a friend that isn't too tech savy and has never used a Linux distro.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "overwrite existing OS".  You mean, wipe the existing OS completely from the drive and replace it?  All OSes can do that.  Or do you mean, run the new OS inside the existing OS partition like Wubi?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, they all happily reformat the disk as part of the installation if you tell them to. If you are experimenting, you might want to partition the disk into, say, 10Gb partitions and install alternative distros on different partitions.

Comment: Great idea! Just need to stock pile the ISOs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of the other Linux distros such as Mint, Zorin, and Deepin will have the same basic UI as other distros like Debian and Ubuntu. Which means that you can overwrite an existing OS.